# Can not change style of html element assigned to variable in a function

Tags: javascript

I am working on a pong in browser and I'm having some problems with things not working as expected

Basically, I need this to work:

```
let grid = document.getElementById('grid');
let ball; //declared outside of function as global variable

function setup() {
    grid.innerHTML += '<div id="ball"></div>'; //this works
    ball = document.getElementById("ball");
    ball.style.width = "10px"; //this works
    ball.style.height = "10px"; //this works
}

function moveBall(x, y) {
    alert(ball.width); //outputs 10px
    ball.style.left = x + "px"; //doesn't do anything
    ball.style.top = y + "px"; //doesn't do anything
}

setup();
moveBall(20, 20);
```

In the function moveBall, I can get the width for example from the ball, but I can not change the width. I can however change the width if I the function like this:

```
function moveBall(x, y) {
    ball = document.getElementById("ball");
    alert(ball.width); //outputs 10px
    ball.style.left = x + "px"; //doesn't do anything
    ball.style.top = y + "px"; //doesn't do anything
}
```

I hope this is clear, I've been looking for a reason for this behaviour for hours but can't seem to find a fix. Please help :)
(also, ignore how to code might not make sense since I cut down a lot of it which doesn't affect this problem).

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine on my side.

**Possible Reason**

The thing is, `width is a string when fetching using style`. You have to get `width` in `number/float` and add the desired width number to it. Then, you have to add `px` string normally and everything will work as expected.

```js
let grid = document.getElementById('grid');
let ball;

function setup() {
    grid.innerHTML += '<div id="ball"></div>'; 
    ball = document.getElementById("ball");
    ball.style.width = "10px";
    ball.style.height = "10px"; 
}

//this is working fine for me
function moveBall(x, y) {
    ball.style.position = "absolute"; //<-- add position absolute
    ball.style.width = parseInt(ball.style.width.slice(0,-2))+10+'px';
    ball.style.height = parseInt(ball.style.height.slice(0,-2))+10+'px';
    ball.style.left = x + "px"; 
    ball.style.top = y + "px"; 
}

setup();


let x = 0, y =0;
setInterval(() => {
  x += 20;
  y += 10;
  moveBall(x, y);
},1000);
```

```css
#grid{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

#ball{
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="grid"></grid>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I made a reply to my post with an answer, since it was too long to post as actual reply

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the effort you put in! What you made does seem to work but if I combine it with the other code I wrote, it doesn't work anymore. This is what my setup actually looks like, and something in there is making it not work.

```
    function setup() {
        grid.innerHTML += '<div id="ball"></div>';
        ball = document.getElementById("ball");
        ball.style.width = BALLWIDTH + "px";
        ball.style.height = BALLHEIGHT + "px";

        grid.innerHTML += '<div id="player1"></div>';
        player1 = document.getElementById("player1");
        player1.style.width = PLAYERWIDTH + "px";
        player1.style.height = PLAYERHEIGHT + "px";
        player1.style.right = DISTANCEFROMWALL + "px";

        grid.innerHTML += '<div id="player2"></div>';
        player2 = document.getElementById("player2");
        player2.style.width = PLAYERWIDTH + "px";
        player2.style.height = PLAYERHEIGHT + "px";
        player2.style.left = DISTANCEFROMWALL + "px";
    }
```